# Android app that sends sms from file?

Tags: android, sms

Is it possible to design an app that reads a formated text file and sends it? The goal is to have a pc program that creates sms to be sent to a list of numbers. It then sends it to an Android phone, running an app that gets the data in the text file and takes care of sendind the sms's.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. You can use [Sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) to communicate the PC application and the Android app  and [SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html) to send messages.